# Internal Server Error

Tags: apache-http-server

I am trying to make a Serial Communication from my local webserver, so I made a c++ file and compiled it that it makes the actual communication and compiled it with GCC:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

char c = 2;
char hexdata = (c & 0xFF);

int main () {

  fstream fs;
  fs.open ("/dev/ttyS0", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

  fs << hexdata;

  fs.close();

  return 0;
}
```

So far it works and I can read the sent data. Now I copied it into /usr/lib/cgi-bin and named it serialOut.cgi, and tried executing it from terminal and it works as well, but when I try to open it from the browser it gives me an internal error:[image]

Though I have another two cgi script in the same directory working well. I tried checking the permissions and it was okay as well:

```
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 34408 Mar 30 18:37 serialout.cgi
```

Also, error.log has no errors. What is the cause of this problem, and how can I solve it?

---

### EDIT

I've edited my code and now the Internal Server error is gone, and it shows a message, but the serial data is still not sent.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

char c = 2;
char hexdata = static_cast<char>(c & 0xFF);

int main () {

  fstream fs;
  fs.open ("/dev/ttyS0", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

  fs << hexdata;

  fs.close();
  cout << "Content-type: text/html" << endl << endl;
  cout << "<html><body>Done!</body></html>";

  return 0;
}
```

[image]

I tried adding an alias to /dev/ to the actual directory /dev/, but still that didn't solve anything. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your program doesn’t look like a CGI program. It doesn’t return anything.

Comment: @DanielB  what is it missing?? I just need it to send the serial data nothing more?

Comment: No, it needs to respond to the request. First optional headers, then a blank line, then content. So a minimal program would need to respond with at least a line break. Luckily, [there’s a book on that](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/index.html).

Comment: @DanielB  can you please see my edit?

Comment: So add some form of debugging do your code? From what you#re saying it's working if you execute it individually? What permissions is it executed with? Does that user have the permission to send the data?

Comment: Yes i am running it from root account in terminal, but i don't know if I need any permissions from my browser @Seth

Comment: Your browser shouldn't matter, except you do some form of impersonation. The CGI might be executed as a different user. I'm not all certain but usually it should be the webserver user and he might be lacking the permission to use the device or similar. You might try to set a sticky bit on the file. In addition you should perform some form of error handling in your code. Currently it has none.

Comment: Oh yeah, trying to run it as the http user is a great idea. Depending on your security requirements you could make it SetUID root, but that’s generally a bad idea, especially if it’ll take input in the future.

Comment: @DanielB setting the setUID root worked, thanks so much